# Why do I not get a standard normal random variable after applying central limit theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$ has $ P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1 ) = 1/2$.

I am trying to use central limit theorem to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(S_n < \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{n}\right)$$

My attempt is that: $E(S_n) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_n) = n$, hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(S_n < \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}< \frac{\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{n} - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\frac{S_n}{n} < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3n}\right) = 0.5$$

Do I use CLT correctly? Why is $\frac{S_n}{n}$ not a standard normal random variable?

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: @callculus42 Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not correct! CLT gives $\Pr(S_n/\sqrt{n}<1/2)\to \Pr(Z<1/3)$ with $Z\sim N(0,1).$

Comment: $S_n$ is a simple symmetric random walk, not $X_i$; $X_i$ is a Rademacher random variable (and $X_i$'s are iid)

Comment: @vanderWolf Thank you, you are right.

Comment: In $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$, there is no $n$ on the RHS.  So how do you get $Var(S_n)=n$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right. I have a mistake on the summation. $Var(S_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = n \times 1 = n$

Answer (score 1):

I see what the problem is. In the formula of central limit theorem, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are $X_i$'s mean and variance but not $S_n$'s mean and variance.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that $\operatorname{E}[S_n] = 0$.  For the variance, since the $X_i$ are independent,

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[S_n] &\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i] \\
&= n \operatorname{Var}[X_1] \\
&= n \left((1 - 0)^2 \Pr[X_1 = 1] + (-1-0)^2 \Pr[X_1 = -1]\right) \\
&= n. \end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[S_n \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\right]
&= \Pr\left[\frac{S_n - \operatorname{E}[S_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[S_n]}} \le \frac{\sqrt{n}/3 - 0}{\sqrt{n}} \right] =  \Pr\left[\frac{S_n - \operatorname{E}[S_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[S_n]}} \le \frac{1}{3} \right].
\end{align}$$
As $n \to \infty$, $$\frac{S_n - \operatorname{E}[S_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[S_n]}} \to Z$$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable; hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr\left[S_n \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\right] = \Pr[Z \le 1/3].$$

If you don't like the application of the CLT in this manner, you can also do it on the sample mean instead of the sample total; i.e., define $$\bar X_n = \frac{S_n}{n}$$ and we have

$$\Pr\left[S_N \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\right] = \Pr\left[\bar X_n \le \frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}}\right] = \Pr\left[\frac{\bar X_n - \operatorname{E}[\bar X_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\bar X_n]}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{n}} - 0}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}\right],$$

since the variance of $\bar X_n$ is simply $\frac{1}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}[S_n] = \frac{1}{n}$.